# Lower Bounding Set Cover's Approximation Ratio

Tags: set-cover

I am reading Slavik's paper [A Tight Analysis of Greedy Set Cover](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677497908877).  Specifically, Slavik considers the unweighted version of set cover where the ground set is ${U = \{1,\ldots,m\}}$ for arbitrarily large $m$. There is a collection of subsets ${S = \{S_1,\ldots,S_n\}}$ that is a cover of $U$.  The goal is to find the smallest subcover ${S^* \subset S}$ that is a cover of $U$.

Let ${\textrm{Opt}:= \vert S^* \vert}$ be the size of the optimal solution and let $G$ be the size of the solution found by the traditional greedy algorithm that selects the subset that covers the most remaining elements.  Slavik proves a bound that (see Eqs. (1) and (2))

$$ \ln m - \ln\ln m - 0.31 < \frac{G}{\textrm{Opt}} < \ln m - \ln\ln m + 0.78$$

What confuses me is how the approximation ratio can be lower bounded by a function of $m$. It seems to me that for arbitrary $m$, it would be possible for ${\frac{G}{\textrm{Opt}} = 1}$ (e.g., let $S_1 \in S$ be set ${\{1,\ldots,m-1\}}$ and let ${S_2 \in S}$ be set ${\{m\}}$ in which case it seems ${G = \textrm{Opt} = 2}$).

Clearly, I am missing something fundamental.  Am I misunderstanding the lower bound on the approximation ratio entirely?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should read the lower bound as: there exists an instance with $m$ items such that $\frac{G}{\text{Opt}} \ge \log m - \log \log m - 0.31$.

Comment: Alternatively, Slavik is interested in the worst possible approximation ratio, as a function of $m$.